# Generate Random Strings in JAVA from given options using java.util.random

Tags: java

I am making a rock paper scissors game in JAVA. I am taking and input from the user (option1 is the String name) and then I want to generate a random text which should only be rock, paper, or scissors so that the user can then play with the user.

Comment: Hint: you have three options to pick from... that suggests you want to generate an integer with value 0, 1 or 2. Can you find a method in `Random` that would help you do that? Think about how you might then translate that number into a string...

Answer (score 0):

There're many options: Use a `Map<Integer, String>` and then generate a random integer value from 0 to 2.

Other option: Use a `String[3]`, you also may use a List, and then generate a random integer value from 0 to 2 to pick one element.

Other option: Create an Enum and use the Enum.values() to get the possible values, then generate a random integer value from 0 to 2 to pick one element.

And there are many other alternatives.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. I still didn't get it. Can you help me with the code?

Comment: If you want to learn, you must create the code. Just think how to solve the puzzle, what would you do if you were a computer?, write a sequence of steps to obtain a result, and then convert it into Java code. I'll give you a last hint: check this javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)